# Placing a shape inside another shape using opencv

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I have two images and I need to place the second image inside the first image. The second image can be resized, rotated or skewed such that it covers a larger area of the other images as possible. As an example, in the figure shown below, the green circle need to be placed inside the blue shape:

[image: example 1: green circle inside blue image]

Here the green circle is transformed such that it covers a larger area. Another example is shown below:

[image: example 2: green circle inside blue image]

Note that there may be some multiple results. However, any similar result is acceptable as shown in the above example.

How do I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a good solution, but if you do not find a better solution, it might help. Find the outer range of both shapes. Now you can use an evolutionary algorithm in combination with image processing. Repeat the following operation in a loop: Randomly change the second piece. Resize it, rotate it or perform any other operations on it; But so that it does not exceed the size of the first piece. If all points of the second part are on the first part (it is possible to check it with image processing algorithms), save that image in list of candidates.

Comment: Repeat this operation many times, for example 1000 times; Choose the best result from the saved list. The best choice could be an example with the largest number of green pixels.

Comment: if you have non-convex shapes, the solution is **hard**, and that's technical term, not an opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested the idea I mentioned earlier in the comments and the output is almost good. It may be better but it takes time. The final code was too much and it depends on one of my old personal projects, so I will not share. But I will explain step by step how I wrote such an algorithm. Note that I have tested the algorithm many times. Not yet 100% accurate.

---

```
for N times do this:
    1. Copy from shape
    2. Transform it randomly
    3. Put the shape on the background
    4-1. It is not acceptable if the shape exceeds the background. Go to 
         the first step.
    4.2. Otherwise we will continue to step 5.
    5. We calculate the length, width and number of shape pixels.
    6. We keep a list of the best candidates and compare these three 
       parameters (W, H, Pixels) with the members of the list. If we 
       find a better item, we will save it.
```

- I set the value of N to **5,000**. The larger the number, the slower the algorithm runs, but the better the result.
- You can use anything for [Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation). [Mirror](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16006157/mirror-an-image-using-python), [Rotate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68878529/2227070), [Shear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shear_matrix), Scale, [Resize](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68878529/2227070), etc. But I used **warpPerspective** for this one.

```py
im1 = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/Back.png')
im2 = cv2.imread(sys.path[0]+'/Shape.png')
bH, bW = im1.shape[:2]
sH, sW = im2.shape[:2]


# TopLeft, TopRight, BottomRight, BottomLeft of the shape
_inp = np.float32([[0, 0], [sW, 0], [sW, sH], [0, sH]])
cx = random.randint(5, sW-5)
ch = random.randint(5, sH-5)
o = 0
# Random transformed output
_out = np.float32([
            [random.randint(-o, cx-1), random.randint(1-o, ch-1)],
            [random.randint(cx+1, sW+o), random.randint(1-o, ch-1)],
            [random.randint(cx+1, sW+o), random.randint(ch+1, sH+o)],
            [random.randint(-o, cx-1), random.randint(ch+1, sH+o)]
])

# Transformed output
M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(_inp, _out)
t = cv2.warpPerspective(shape, M, (bH, bW))
```

- You can use **countNonZero** to find the number of pixels and **findContours** and **boundingRect** to find the shape size.

```py
def getSize(msk):
    cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(msk, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
    cnts.sort(key=lambda p: max(cv2.boundingRect(p)[2],cv2.boundingRect(p)[3]), reverse=True)
    w,h=0,0
    if(len(cnts)>0):
        _, _, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts[0])
    pix = cv2.countNonZero(msk)
    return pix, w, h
```

- To find overlaping of back and shape you can do something like this:
  make a mask from back and shape and use bitwise methods; Change this section according to the software you wrote. This is just an example :)

```py
mskMix = cv2.bitwise_and(mskBack, mskShape)
mskMix = cv2.bitwise_xor(mskMix, mskShape)
isCandidate = not np.any(mskMix == 255)
```

[image]
For example this is not a candidate answer; This is because if you look closely at the image on the right, you will notice that the shape has exceeded the background.

---

I just tested the circle with 4 different backgrounds; And the results:
After **4879** Iterations:

[image]

After **1587** Iterations:

[image]

After **4621** Iterations:

[image]

After **4574** Iterations:

[image]

---

- A few additional points. If you use a method like **medianBlur** to cover the noise in the Background mask and Shape mask, you may find a better solution.
- I suggest you read about [Evolutionary Computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_computation), [Metaheuristic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaheuristic) and [Soft Computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soft_computing) algorithms for better understanding of this algorithm :)

Comment: This is a good solution and thank for the great explanation. What is your approach when you doing random transformation?

Comment: I will explain more step by step and update the solution :)

Comment: Great explanation. Thank you very much